# Check if a file exists or not in shell in a particular directory

Tags: shell, unix

This question might seem silly, but i am stumped, not sure what is wrong.
Anyways, i have a piece of code that checks if a particular file exists in a directory or not.
The code works fine for normal files, by normal files i mean.. something of this sort "abc.xlsx or xaga1.xlsx". The problem is when i pass a file with spaces, it seems to fail, i mean.. the check fails.
I'll go straight to the code:

```
if [ ! -e "$file" ]
then
    echo_time "ERROR: $file does not exist - aborting" >> $fileChangedLog
    exit 1
fi
```

If i check in the log file to which the output is being redirected, i can see the following line:

```
[03/17/16 11:07:09] ERROR: "/opt/just4share/tellabs/tellabs_nodes 2.xlsx" does not exist - aborting
```

but if i **ls** the error path i get the following output:

```
[netcool@HJKPNLIN03 scripts]$ ls -lrt "/opt/just4share/tellabs/tellabs_nodes 2.xlsx"
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 netcool ncoadmin 17412 Mar 17 10:43 /opt/just4share/tellabs/tellabs_nodes 2.xlsx
```

This confirms the file exists however, my code fails to find it. What am i doing wrong here? :|

Edit: I have also tried the **-f** switch in place of the **-e** switch

Comment: It looks like your `$file` variable contains the double quotes, so the searched file is `"/opt...`not `/opt...` (the log message is clear about this). How is the variable `$file` constructed?

Answer (score -1):

Well, i figured the problem, i was appending the double quote character to the path variable **$file** in an attempt to enclose the path in double quotes, removing the double quotes did the trick.

Old code:

```
file="\"$directory/$file\""
```

New code:

```
file="$directory/$file"
```

Comment: Nowhere in the question do you show this code, this it literally useless to anyone but you.

Comment: @123 This was part of another script, however, i put this part of the solution considering the fact that it would be more intuitive than me just putting "solved".